# Svn copy/move with history

Tags: svn, svn-copy

Can I copy or move folder in svn as

```
svn copy URL URL
svn move URL URL
```

and save hishory?

There http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re07.html and there http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re18.html saids about copy/move folder with history as `WC WC` only, is it true?

Client v1.7, Server v1.6, move and copy within single repository.

Comment: You might also check out the newer documentation (i.e.) http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but only within the same repository. You can type `svn help copy` to check that.

Comment: Sorry that asked two question. I use single repository. Can you clarify you answer? Becouse I can't find privious history when copy or move folder as svn copy URL URL or svn move URL URL.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i can't tell you the SVN command line commands, but
after copy of the file and commit you see in TortoiseSVN / "Show Log" the full history.

You can check "Stop on copy/rename" in the log Messages window if you want to avoid this.